# How do I mod_rewrite my URL to hide the subfolder?

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL is:

```
http://website.com/folder/blah.php
```

How do I write a rewrite rule so that the request:

```
http://website.com/blah.php
```

Gets silently redirected to /folder/ ?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for; to show the contents of mywebsite.com/blog/page.php when a user visits mywebsite.com/page.php, all I kept finding was code that redirects to mywebsite.com/page.php and hence giving a 404 error! Thanks even though this wasn't my question

Answer (score 0):

Really?

```
RewriteRule ^/blah.php /folder/blah.php
```

doesn't work for you?

See also

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Edit, based on the comment...

If your current rule is

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /dms/$1
```

then you should probably precede it with a condition than won't match if the rule has already been applied.  For example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dms
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /dms/$1
```

Otherwise you end up looping with

blah.php -> /dms/blah.php -> /dms/dms/blah.php -> /dms/dms/dms/blah.php -> etc.

Comment: `blah.php` was an example. There's more than one file I need to redirect. I tried `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /dms/$1` but it's not working

Comment: @tom, what is "not working" about it? If that is your only rule, then it seems likely you're in an infinite loop.  After the first rewrite, the rewritten URL will match again and be rewritten again.